# converting an object to line

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching, pattern-recognition

I have an object and want to convert this object to line in matlab. I don't want to find the edges, because for this object the edges will have two sides which I just want the central line. Is there any way or function in matlab to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [morphological skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) of the image.

You can find that with the function `bwmorph`by:

```
bwmorph(BW,'skel',Inf);
```

See [Docs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html)

Comment: Small note.  You need to invert the image seen in the OP's post before invoking `bwmorph`. +1 BTW!